# Couchbase N1QL's select statement with named parameters in PHP

Tags: php, couchbase, sql++

I was trying to use N1QL in PHP...this first one is working:
1)

```
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString("select count(*) from mybucket where type = 'user'");
$res = $myBucket->query($query);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["$1"]=>
    int(58)
  }
}
```

2) When I changed to named parameter(s), it failed:

```
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString("select count(*) from mybucket where type = $type");
$res = $myBucket->query($query, ['type' => 'user']);
```

I got 'PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: type...' error

Can anyone help to instruct me the correct syntax to use named parameters for N1QL in PHP?

my couchbase server is 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track.  The problem is that you are using `$type` in a PHP string, which is causing the PHP processor to attempt to replace it with a variable named `type`.  You should wrap your N1QL string in single-quotes rather than double-quotes to avoid having the PHP interpreter attempt to do this kind of string processing.

Also Couchbase PHP SDK provides API for setting named params:

```
$query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString('SELECT airportname FROM `travel-sample` WHERE city=$city AND type=$airport');
$query->namedParams(['city' => "Los Angeles", 'type' => "airport"]);
```

This is preferred way to supply named parameters.